# Access subclass variables in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have a Shop class that has an array list of type Worker, and I have two classes that inherit (extend) from Worker, called Stocker and Cashier.

My Stocker class adds the variable

```
int stamina;
```

and my Cashier class adds the variable

```
int patience;
```

Within Shop, I have an ArrayList named workers of type Worker, my questions are:

1) Is it wrong to be adding objects of types Stocker and Cashier into workers even though they both extend from the Worker class?

2) How can I access the variables of the subclasses from the ArrayList? I've tried to use:

```
workers.get(0).getStamina();
```

(knowing for a fact that I have added a class of type Stocker to my ArrayList at index 0) - however this does not work..

How can I freely access and use these subclasses from an ArrayList of type superclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast a `Worker` to a `Stocker` to do that:

```
((Stocker) workers.get(0)).getStamina();
```

However you may want to consider changing your design so that you do not have a list of items of different types.

Comment: So make 3 different ArrayLists? One for Worker, Stocker, and Cashier? Is it wrong to make an ArrayList using subclasses of a superclass?

Comment: If you have an ArrayList, you should normally use the elements in the same way. Since you want to call different methods, 3 lists may be better

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList can store Workers and Stockers in the same collection, but if you say `ArrayList<Worker>` then the collection only knows about Workers and not Stockers.

You need something like:

```
Worker worker = workers.get(0);
if (worker instanceof Stocker)
{
    Stocker stocker = (Stocker)worker;
    //stocker.getStamina();
```